# Division to Two decimal Places in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, division

How do you create a function in Javascript which, given a number, returns how many hundreds fit into that number - and then rounds to 2 decimal places?

The code I have:

```
function howManyHundreds(num) {

   return (num / 100.00);

}
```

However, it just returns solid numbers. For ex. 55/100 = 0, instead of .55.

The assignment suggests using the modulo operator (%) to help, but I am unsure how to use that for rounding to 2 decimal places, not just the remainder.

Comment: That function will correctly return fractions. How are you *calling* the function?

Comment: Your function works correctly. Can you provide us context?

Comment: *"However, it just returns solid numbers. For ex. 55/100 = 0, instead of .55."* No, it doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/9cr7guxm/

Answer (score 1):

Calling your function here displays .55 in alert box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function howManyHundreds(num) {
   return (num / 100.00);
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<script>
alert(howManyHundreds(55));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use the mod operator you could do something like this:
(100 % .55 = .45)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function howManyHundreds(num) {
   var mod = 100.00 % num
   return mod.toFixed(2)
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<script>
alert(howManyHundreds(.55));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you have looks valid and returns the value you are expecting.
How ever this is how I tested opening Chrome Console and define below steps and you can verify the output.

step 1 : caller = {};
step 2 (in case you want to fix the output by 2 decimals : caller.execute = function howManyHundreds(num) {

return Number((Number(num) / 100.00).toFixed(2));

}
step 2 (in case you want to round the output) : caller.execute = function howManyHundreds(num) {

return Math.round((Number(num) / 100.00).toFixed(2));

}

step  3 : caller.execute(3444); // Test your output.
Hope this helps.